# Can you see the difference between these two pieces of code?

Tags: python

I am on Codewars and my code shows an error besides being the same as the solution. I can't see any difference, can you help me?

```
    if len(numbers) <= 1: 
       return []
    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    return numbers
```

and this

```
 if len(numbers) <= 1: return []
    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    return numbers
```

Comment: The indentation in the 2nd code is wrong. Since you have the single line if statement, nothing else should be indented.

Comment: second one won't execute

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not correct in case of second code. The following codes do the same thing. There is no difference.

**1. code:**

```
if len(numbers) <= 1: 
    return []
numbers.remove(min(numbers))
return numbers
```

**2. code:**

```
if len(numbers) <= 1: return []
numbers.remove(min(numbers))
return numbers
```

---

**NOTE:** The `PEP8` suggests to avoid Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line).

Let's see the `PEP8` documentation: https://pep8.org/

Related part of `PEP8`:

```
Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged.

Yes:

if foo == 'blah':
    do_blah_thing()
do_one()
do_two()
do_three()

Rather not:

if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
```

**EDIT:**

You can see the complete code with tests below. As you will see, there is no difference between the functions.

**Code:**

```
def first_test_function(numbers):
    if len(numbers) <= 1:
        return []
    print("Min number in first function: {}".format(min(numbers)))
    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    return numbers


def second_test_function(numbers):
    if len(numbers) <= 1: return []
    print("Min number in second function: {}".format(min(numbers)))
    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    return numbers


first_test_list = [5]
second_test_list = [1, 4, 8, 9]

print("Result of first test list.\n"
      "First test function: {first_test}\n"
      "Second test function: {second_test}\n".format(first_test=first_test_function(first_test_list),
                                                     second_test=second_test_function(first_test_list)))

print("Result of second test list.\n"
      "First test function: {first_test}\n"
      "Second test function: {second_test}\n".format(first_test=first_test_function(second_test_list),
                                                     second_test=second_test_function(second_test_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Result of first test list.
First test function: []
Second test function: []

Min number in first function: 1
Min number in second function: 4
Result of second test list.
First test function: [8, 9]
Second test function: [8, 9]
```

Comment: But The Second Code Is The One Working Correctly. First one Is The One With The Error! I Don't Understand What The Hell IS Going on Here. Even If I Just go Ahead And delete The indentaion of the first to match the second. it still doesn't work.!

Comment: Impossible! :) I have tested it. My answer has been edited and I have added my tests. You can see the functions work as expected in my answer.

Comment: @XooT Can you share the error, which you are getting?